# Laravel 4: Pass model from filter to controller action

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, filter, controller

My application has 3 different scenarios:

1. Controller action is accessible for authorized users only
2. Controller action is accessible for non-authorized users only
3. Controller action is accessible for any user, but auth check is done

First two scenarios are handled by simple filters, and since all scenarios are logically similar, it seems that the remaining scenario should be processed by filter too.

So, what I would like to do:
When user accesses some specific controller action (i.e. `HomeController@getIndex`), the filter should check whether the user is authorized or no, set controller's `$user` property to `Auth::user()` value and share this value between all the views. Here's the code I came up with:

```
Router::filter('auth', function() {
    $route = Str::parseCallback(Route::currentRouteAction(), null); // 0 - controller name, 1 - controller action name

    $controller = App::make($route[0]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $controller->user = $user;
    View::share('user', $user);

    return $controller->{$route[1]}();
});
```

This code works, however the controller is invoked twice (i.e. when controller action has no `return` construct), and auth filter invokes controller before any other `'before'` filters are called.

**Second solution:**
Create `AuthController`, and use it's constructor to set `$user` property, however the constructor will be called for every child controller action (I would like to run it on specific actions only, so I think filters are the way to go).

**Third solution:**
Create `UserRepository` and code a method, that will do all the auth stuff, and call it from actions that need auth (not setting `$user` property). This solutions seems to be an overkill for a few lines of code.

**Fourth solution:**
Pass `Auth::user()` value to controller action directly (as a param), but I haven't found any convenient way to do so yet.

Is there any kind of "best practice" solution for handling auth in described way?
Is there any other ways of solving this problem?

Comment: Do you have a service provider setup for when you are instantiating your controller with `App::make()`?  Is there a reason you can't use the automatic dependency injection in your controllers?  If all you want to do is pass the authenticated user's model to all your views, why not just use `View::share('user', Auth::user());`

Comment: @user3158900 No, I don't have any custom service providers for controllers. "Is there a reason you can't use the automatic dependency injection in your controllers" - this part is not clear to me. Could you please show by example? And yes, I want to share variable between views AND (set controller property OR pass variable to SPECIFIC (not every) controller action in any other way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user3158900 I did some research and came up with another solution.
Since placing `expose` method inside `User` model is kinda unintuitive, it seemed right to extend authorization facade.

**This is my final solution:**

Create a Guard class in app/extensions/Auth/ directory. This class extends Laravel's native `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` class.

```
<?php namespace Extensions\Auth;

class Guard extends \Illuminate\Auth\Guard {

    public function exposeUser() {
        $user = \Auth::user();

        \View::share('user', $user);

        return $user;
    }

}
```

Create an extensions.php file in app directory and include this file into app/global/start.php.

```
require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/extensions.php';
```

New extensions.php file contains following code (this code adds new auth driver):

```
Auth::extend('eloquent+', function() {
    return new \Extensions\Auth\Guard(
        new \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider(App::make('hash'), \Config::get('auth.model')),
        App::make('session.store')
    );
});
```

Set auth config's (app/config/auth.php) `$model` property to `'eloquent+`' (this makes our auth use `'eloquent+'` as auth driver).

Modify composer.json to reflect new autoload class map.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/extensions"
    ]
},
```

Finally run `composer dump-autoload`.

Now you can use your Auth::user() and other auth methods as usually, plus we can share model between views and access it from any action simply calling `Auth::exposeUser()` in our controller actions.

It would also be nice to get some feedback about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would probably be to create a UserRepository class and service providers for each controller that  would inject the user repository, but like you said, probably overkill for something simple.

Maybe an easier solution is to add a function to BaseController.php which sets the user.

```
public function setUser()
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();
}
```

And then whenever you need to set the user, just call `$controller->setUser();`.  If you always need the controller to do this, just call `$this->setUser()` in the constructor so it's always available.

Comment: I didn't think about this way of achieving desired result. Your solution is very simple yet solves the problem. I think I should move in this direction and extend `User` model with `current` method (like `$user = User::current()`). Gonna try it tomorrow. Thank you!